# python class instance as an attribute (constant) of the same class

Tags: python

I am writing a package to manipulate binary trees, and I want an empty tree to be a real tree, i. e., it cannot be *None*. My simplified code looks like:

```
class BT:

    EMPTY = ""             ## place holder

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left = self.right = BT.EMPTY
        self.data = data

    def isempty(self):
        return self is BT.EMPTY
...
BT.EMPTY = BT("anything")
```

However I wonder whether there isn't a more elegant pythonic solution.

Comment: This could be easily misleading as `BT.EMPTY.EMPTY` is now possible. Better to make an *empty tree* an instance with some attribute/property defined/set and not make it a class attribute.

Comment: can you clarify what do you mean by a empty tree? Something like a tree object that after deletions has no data? Am i guessing right?

Comment: BT.EMPTY.EMPTY is not possible -- it is a class and not an instance attribute.

Comment: Yes, an empty tree has no data but still is instance of a tree.